# Copy multiple files from s3 bucket greater than certain time where the date and time are given in filename using lambda function python

Tags: python, file, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, copy

I have multiple files in s3 bucket say abc_28092021_043221.csv, abc_28092021_202918.csv and abc_29092021_202918.csv.

I would like copy files to another s3 bucket, greater than '2021-09-28 04:32:21' using a lambda function in py.

Can you please help me with basic coding format to achieve this?

Comment: welcome to SO! Please, show your attempts and where you struggle at.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.